# Put href in onclick event

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a page containing different links pointing to several PDF's. The links are dynamically created so I can't edit the HTML directly.

```
<a href="https://example.com/presentation-1.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
<a href="https://example.com/presentation-2.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

I'm trying to open every link that points to a pdf in a new window.
This is what I got so far:

```
$("a[href$='.pdf']").attr("onclick", 'https://example.com','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;");
```

Ofcourse the new window has to contain the pdf. So the https://example.com in the code should contain the href of the correct PDF. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: [`target="_blank"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) should be sufficient. Why the javascript?

Comment: The Javascript is intended to make the new window smaller. As a popup.

Comment: Don't do that. Doing that treats it as a popup which is blocked by modern browsers. Let the user decide how they want new views to show. By default, this is a new tab loaded in the background. Ideally, you'd just link normally to the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try below snippet

```js
$(document).on('click', "a[href$='.pdf']", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href_val = $(this).attr('href');
    window.open(href_val, '', ["width=" + 600,"height=" + 600, 'status=1', 'toolbar=0'].join(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com/presentation-1.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
<a href="https://example.com/presentation-2.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Note - New window will not open here because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.